# Using ListJS with Masonry

Tags: javascript, html, masonry, listjs

I'm doing a project where I use Listjs and Masonry together. I wanted it when I paged and searched for something the masonry rearranged the items. However this is not happening. I leave here my code:

HTML CODE

```
<div class="container" id="posts">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="grid list">
                    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>sports, fails</div><img src='assets/images/posts/1.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>sports, football</div><img src='assets/images/posts/2.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>sports, tenis</div><img src='assets/images/posts/1.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>sports</div><img src='assets/images/posts/3.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>fail</div><img src='assets/images/posts/1.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>kid</div><img src='assets/images/posts/3.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>teste</div><img src='assets/images/posts/1.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>tete</div><img src='assets/images/posts/5.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>1235</div><img src='assets/images/posts/1.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>1235</div><img src='assets/images/posts/1.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>1235</div><img src='assets/images/posts/3.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>1235</div><img src='assets/images/posts/2.gif'></div>
                    <div class="grid-item"><div class='tag'>1235</div><img src='assets/images/posts/5.gif'></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="pagination-box">
                        <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <input type='text' class='form-control search' placeholder="Search...">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
<script>
// init Masonry
var $grid =  $('.grid');
$grid.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  gutter: 20,
  stagger: 30
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry();
});
</script>
<script>
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'tag' ],
    page: 10,
    plugins: [
      ListPagination({})
    ]
};
var postslist = new List('posts', options);
postslist.on('searchStart', function(){
    $grid.masonry('reloadItems');
});

</script>
```

Comment: And this is what happens when I search and when I paginate:

  General View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Xnv.jpg

  When i do a search: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISg6r.jpg
  When paginate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQT1W.jpg
.
Sorry but I have no reputation for putting the links in the question

Comment: You might want to put the answer as a seperate answer and then accept it as answer. Easier for other people.

Comment: Okay @LuudvanKeulen. I will do this.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen Done! : )

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of testing and debugging, i was able to find a solution to my problem. I had to initialize masonry again in the search and in the pagination. However I found another error, when doing pagination to div  disappeared. The solution I found was to append the div whenever I changed pages.

UPDATED JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
<script>
// init Masonry
var $grid =  $('.grid');
$grid.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  gutter: 20,
  stagger: 30
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry();
});
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'tag' ],
    page: 10,
    pagination: true
    /*plugins: [
      ListPagination({})
    ]*/
};
var postslist = new List('posts', options);
$('.search').on('input',function(){
    $grid.masonry('destroy');
    $grid.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      gutter: 20,
      stagger: 30
    });
});
postslist.on('updated', function(){
    $( ".grid" ).append('<div class="grid-sizer"></div>');
    $grid.masonry('destroy');
    $grid.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      gutter: 20,
      stagger: 30
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope I can help somebody when it's necessary

Thanks